# How to detect if the program run in JAR or not?

Tags: java, jar

How can I detect if the program runs in JAR or not?

I'm asking that, because of the loading resources like pictures, templates etc. Inside a JAR file it will be different.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm asking that, because of the
>   loading resources like pictures,
>   templates etc. Inside a JAR file it
>   will be different.

No, it won't, if you do it correctly.

This will work exactly the same whether the class is loaded from a directory, a webserver or a JAR file:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("logo.gif"));
```

Alternatively, use the `getResourceAsStream()` method for maximal flexibility.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, with pictures I don't have this problem. the problem I have is with Freemaker. When running in JAR, template loader class requires  leading "/" in the path to template's directory and while not in JAR, it works without it.

Comment: Actually, this isn't a really good, flexible way of doing it. But on smaller problems, its fine. Main problem: you can only reference classes in subfolders of the class you use to get the resources. So a) you will need to put your resources deep into your package hierarchy or b) you'll need a class in the default package.

Comment: @piegames: I think it's actually good to put resources with the classes that use them, but if you don't want to do that, you can put them in whatever separate directory hierarchy you like and access them by calling getResource() on the classloader instead (and specify the full path relative to the classpath root).

Answer (score 4):

Examine `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();` - this'll give you a directory or a jar.

Answer (score 1):

Use [getResourceAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to attempt to retrieve the resource. If you are not running in a jar, or the resource cannot be found, the method returns null. In that case you're not running in a jar and must use a FileInputStream or other method to retrieve your resource.

Strictly speaking, this retrieves resources that are on the classpath, but the effect is pretty much what you appear to need.

Answer (score 1):

The application starts with a `main` method in some Class, let's call it `com.example.Main`.

You can use this code to print the URL of the class file that has been used to load it:

```
System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/example/Main.class"));
```

This is the URL that has been used to load your applications main class and, if the URL String starts with `jar:file:`, then the class file has been loaded from a jar.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially determine it by inspecting the `java.class.path` system property. That's unlikely a good idea however. Instead you should use [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). Then just put your assets in your project under the same logical directory structure as they as packaged into the jar.